# Is there a trick to automatically delete semantically expired e-mails?

Tags: email

There are categories of e-mails messages, that are not spam, but which loose relevance after certain date. 
Examples:

- promotions from bestbuy valid on black friday only
- invitations for events that can be deletede after the event

Is there a mechanism for handling that sort of e-mails (maybe a field in the e-mail "expires after" I am not aware of), or auto-detect such e-mails?

Comment: No, there is no such mechanism, and if there were, it isn't being used by mailers as described.

Comment: @Randolph Potter: your comment is a perfectly valid answer.

Comment: I've made it a perfectly valid answer :-).

Comment: and i gave you a perfectly valid +1 :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [RFC 2076 Section 3.8](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2076#section-3.8) there is **no standard way** to send the expiration date.

`Expires` and `Expiry-date` -headers exist but, as said, they are not standardized. Quick look through some newsletters in my inbox confirmed that these are not commonplace.

Some e-mail clients can send this header with the email. I just tested it with Outlook 2007 and the expiration-related part in the message header looks like this:

`Expiry-Date: Fri, 10 Dec 2010 18:00:00 +0200`

*(It is funny to notice that the used header is `Expiry-Date` which was tentatively designed (in 1997 ie. 13 years ago) to be replaced with `Expires` header. But this just shows how obsolete its usage is)*

It *might* be in use in some corporate environments where it is known that every e-mail client can use the expiration header, in Outlook to Outlook type of messaging for example.

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no such mechanism, and if there were, it isn't being used by mailers as described.

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of anything that would work in the general case as you'd need to be able to parse the e-mail and recognise "end dates".

The only thing I can think of is that you add the expiry date as a "property" or flag on the e-mail and then have a process that runs daily checking for dates earlier than today and delete the message.

However, I don't know how you'd go about coding that in your e-mail client (even if you'd said which one it was!).

Comment: If you have your own e-mail server, this task is fairly simple. Currently I was looking for a way to exactly doing that, as I get many notification e-mails from my productive environment. Those notifications are important, but once I read them or a certain amount of time passes, they are absolutely worthless. So, implementing a daily iteration over all inbox e-mails seems to be a good idea. `grep -Rl 'Expiry-Date:'` could retrieve all those e-mails for further processing (parsing date, comparing and deleting if necessary).